# Error SSL "La operación no se completo correctamente" al enviar un correo en php laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

Estoy trabajando en proyecto web con Laravel PHP y tengo en especial un formulario que contiene un input el cual el usuario pone su correo y al finalizar el formulario nos devuelve un pdf con la información y al mismo tiempo nos envía la información del formulario al correo.

Pero he notado y me han dicho que después de digamos varios envíos o varios registros, al dar `clic` en guardar la información o dar un `Submit` me genera esta pantalla de error aunque  si me envía la información al correo pero no me genera ningún registro en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es mi configuración de mi `.ENV`, anteriormente tenia el puerto `587` y me salio peor por que mas me salia este error.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=XXX.XXX.XX.106 
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=preregistro
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

PUSHER_APP_ID=XXXX15
PUSHER_APP_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX60
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXf9
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=us2

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

esta es la configuracion del archivo mail.php dentro de la carpeta config

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'preregistro@email.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'preregistro@email.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'empresa'),
        'subject' => env('MAIL_FROM_SUBJECT', 'Preregistro'),


    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
    'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
        //    'allow_self_signed' => true,
           'verify_peer' => false,
           'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
     ],

];
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

aunque no veo todo tu controlador, me parece que lo estas complicando, la forma mas simple seria:
Recibir los datos del formulario, en este caso supongamos, un nombre.

```
$nombre =$request->Input("nombre");
```

Asignar ese nombre a un array, que vas a pasarle a la funcion que envia el correo.

```
$contenido = ['nombre' => $nombre];
```

y recordemos que Laravel puede utilizar un template del email, donde tienen el diseño, etc, al cual la funcion junta con la variable nombre, y teermina enviando todo el conjunto, algo asi:

```
Mail::send('mi-template-html', ['contenido' => $contenido], function ($m) use ($contenido) {
    $m->from('micorreoorigen@algo.com', 'miorigen');
    $m->to(['micorreodestino@algo.com'])->subject('EL ASUNTO DEL CORREO');
    $m->cc(['micorreodestinocopia@algo.com']);
});
```

En el temaplate del correo, que deebria estar guaraddo en la carpeta de las resources, views (las vistas) , tendrias algo asi, dentro del codigo html (el .blade):

```
{{ $contenido['nombre'] }}
```

obviamente en el .env configuraste previamente el smtp de micorreoorigen@algo.com, con su password, para la autenticacion.

En el manual de laravel figura como adjuntarle atachs si fuera necesario.

Eso es todo para enviar el correo con Laravel.